# How to prove this inequality in complex numbers?

Tags: inequality

My teacher gave me this problem and I spend about 3 hours of my time on it but failed to prove it. so please describe the idea behind proving this inequality.

Problem :

we know that $|z|< 1$
prove this inequality : $$|\arg(\frac{1+z}{1-z})| < 90^o$$

by the way z here is a complex or mixed number.

Comment: This is not a research question.

Comment: @IanMorris just give me an idea of how to solve. I don't want you to solve it for me.

Comment: I disagree emphatically with those who voted to close saying this belongs on another web site. It does not belong on the internet at all. It is a homework assignment meant to be done by those to whom it was assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main remark is

> $|arg(z)|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ if and only if $\Re (z)>0$

where $\Re(x+iy)=x$ design the real part of a complex number.

\begin{eqnarray}
2\Re\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)&=& \frac{1+z}{1-z}+\frac{1+\bar z}{1-\bar z}\\
&=& \frac{(1+z)(1-\bar z) + (1-z)(1+\bar z)}{|1-z|^2}\\
&=& \frac{1+z-\bar z-|z|^2 + 1-z+\bar z-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2}\\
&=&\frac{2(1-|z|^2)}{|1-z|^2}>0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Yes, that if and only if part is needed. I was about to post a counter example, then I read your answer. +1